# Dynamically Add onClick ActionListener to CheckBox in Android

Tags: java, android

I am creating an application, which creates checkboxes dynamically from the number of entries in the database.

The code runs fine. and creates number of checkboxes. But I want to add onClick Action Listener to the CheckBoxes, dynamically. How to do this.

I am posting the code here:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

int maxCount = cursor.getCount();
CheckBox[] check = new CheckBox[maxCount];

cursor.moveToFirst();
int checkboxid = 100;
int alarm_id;
for(int i=0;i<maxCount;i++)
{
    check[i]= new CheckBox(this);
setCheckBoxId(i+maxCount);
}
```

Now how to add actionlistener to these dynamically created CheckBoxes.

Comment: ya.. I did but this class do not extend Activity class so. and onClickListener is method of View Class. So how to do it.?

Answer (score 2):

below `check[i]= new CheckBox(this);` add this, and your CheckBoxes will have a all clicklistener

```
check[i].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // your code to be executed on click :)
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
check[i]= new CheckBox(this);
check[i].setOnClickListener(this);
```

You will want to check against the checkbox id or set a tag for the text boz when creating it.

```
check[i].setTag(someIdentifier);
```

then use the method

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
                 if (v.getTag.equals(someIdentifier)){
                    //do stuff here
                  }

        }
```

Comment: The below method is just as valid.

Comment: I like your method better because it only uses one Listener, whilest Dodge's method creates a new Listener object for every single checkbox.

Comment: Thanks, yeah its a bit nicer, but means you have to maintain the identifiers and switch/select against them yourself. Dodges method is a little simpler conceptually, if a touch inefficient (especially on dynamic content where you don't know your final number of listeners/box's when coding) . :D

Comment: I tried it.. but the problem is my class is not extending `Activity` so... not able to use view

Comment: Ok, firstly why is your class not extending activity? Surely all UI based things are connected to an Activity or Fragment. If you really want to work in this way i would assume your class is being called from an activity so... get a reference to your underlying activity and setOnClickListener(mActivity) then in your activity class you can set the onClick method here.... but this is kinda messy.... first check that you cant move this method to your underlying activity class.

Comment: here is how I would do it.  SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

int maxCount = cursor.getCount();
CheckBox[] check = new CheckBox[maxCount];

cursor.moveToFirst();
mActivity.createCheckboxFromCursor(cursor);                                    then in your activity class create a method called createCheckboxFromCursor which will then create your boxes using the second half of your code .